# How to create a -15v rail from a +15v power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a +15v power supply rated to 4A, and would like to have a -15v rail that can draw up to 1A.  For the -15v rail would I use a single IC or is there a simple circuit that could accomplish this?

Comment: A TLC555 timer and a few diodes would work if you only needed milliamps of current. No simple circuits to build, so check Amazon.com, DigiKey, Mouser, Newark for pre-made adjustable boost or buck converters with 1 amp output and a negative voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [LM2596](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf?ts=1597113267943&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM2596%253Fqgpn%253Dlm2596) in an inverting configuration.

According to Fig. 19, maximum load current should be around the 1A level.

[image]

There are probably some similar LTxxx products that are more expensive and better in this application. Initial start-up surge tends to be quite large in this configuration, hopefully your 4A capability will handle it.

Edit: For example, the [LTC8364](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8364f.pdf):

[image]

PCB layout and inductor specifications are quite important in a 2MHz converter so be careful to follow all the datasheet recommendations.